VS 2022 Adding .py files in a single project
I'm relatively new to using Visual Studio 2022. I am trying to write code that requires two .py "files."
I have attempted to add a file by using New -> file from the menu but it looks like VS sees this as a completely different project.
Can someone help me out?

Visual Studio is not the same as VS Code. They are different programs.
